# SQL Parameterized Queries with Different Variable Types from VBA?

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-2005

In using SQL and parameterized queries from VBA, I am running into the following problem.

When I construct parameters, I can construct varchar and int parameters individually and use them correctly. However when I mix them, I get the following SQL error:

```
Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int
```

It seems SQL is smashing everything to text when I combine parameters of multiple types.

What do I have to do differently with my code (either VBA/SQL) to allow the third case to work (with parameters of varying types)?

---

Here is the VBA code:

```vb
Sub testAdodbParameters()


    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Cm As ADODB.Command
    Dim Pm As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim Pm2 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim Rs As ADODB.Recordset

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "validConnectionString;"

    Set Cm = New ADODB.Command

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    With Cm
        .ActiveConnection = Cn
        .CommandType = adCmdText

        Set Pm = .CreateParameter("TestInt", adInteger, adParamInput)
        Pm.value = 1

        Set Pm2 = .CreateParameter("TestVarChar", adVarChar, adParamInput, -1)
        Pm2.value = "testhi"


        'this works
        If True Then
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test(TestInt) VALUES(?);"
            .Parameters.Append Pm

        End If

        'this also works
        If False Then
            .Parameters.Append Pm2
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test(TestVarChar) VALUES(?);"

        End If

        'this fails with:
        'Operand type clash: text is incompatible with int
        If False Then
            .Parameters.Append Pm
            .Parameters.Append Pm2
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test(TestVarChar,TestInt) VALUES(?,?);"

        End If

        Set Rs = .Execute
    End With
errHandler:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

Here is the SQL code to generate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    TestVarChar varchar(50),
    TestInt int
);
```

Comment: `Pm` is an Int parameter, but it looks like you're assigning it to the `TestVarChar` column.  Ie. your parameters are switched in position.

Comment: Change your command text to `.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test(TestInt, TestVarChar) VALUES(?,?);"`

Comment: @TimWilliams this is absolutely the case... I suspect this will be the ultimate problem with my more complicated query, too (this is a test example, apparently I replicated some similar problematic logic in my minimal working example... awesome)

Answer (score 0):

You are in VARCHAR, INT order in the query, you can try this:

```
        .Parameters.Append Pm2
        .Parameters.Append Pm
        .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Test(TestVarChar,TestInt) VALUES(?,?);"
```

Does it work ?